# Connecting a domain name to an ip of azure vm

Tags: azure, deployment, dns, virtual-machine, subdomain

Hi I have developed an angular application and trying to deploy it on a vm. I was able to deploy it on the vm. When I enter the ip address of the vm in browser, my application comes up. I have purchased a domain name on godaddy and linked the ip address of my vm to the domain name. So now when i enter my domain name in the browser the application comes up.

Same setup I am trying to do it on my client vm. I have deployed the application on the client vm on azure. I am able to access the application in browser through the ip address of the vm . Now if i try to update the ip address to which my domain is pointing to the client vm, the application doesn't come up in the browser. I get this in the broswer

```
internal error - server connection terminated
```

Is this because my client vm has some security/administrator/network rules , I am not able to point my domain to that ip ? Can someone help me with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case if you're able to access the application on Azure VM via VM's public IP address successfully, I think it's good for the networking connection with an application port between your PC and Azure VM. If not, you could check if the NSG or firewall inside the Azure VM is blocking the application port.

The main issue might be the DNS. I suggest removing the existing `A` record which is pointing to your old VM then add a new `A` record pointing to the new VM's Public IP address. Also, you could try these steps to see if they’ll help:

- Run `ipconfig/flushdns` in Command Prompt as an administrator
- Clear the browser cache
- Clear cookies
- Refresh the page (F5)
- Try a different browser

Hope this could help you.

Comment: Hi @Nancy done as above, but didn't work, how long should i wait typically when I add a new `A` record pointing to the new VMs IP address?

Comment: It may need to wait for the  TTL or DNS cache to expire. In some case, it's about 48 hours https://support.stackpath.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001079683-How-long-does-it-take-for-DNS-changes-to-be-reflected-

Comment: Does this issue get fixed?